# Ruby - [BUG] Bus Error at 0x000000010add5a98 ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-darwin22]

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, bus-error

I work on a MacOs Ventura 13.2.1. and have a Rails app, using ruby 3.1.2
I have this error when I open my local server (rails s) :

```
/Users/emmanuelleducolombier/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:227: [BUG] Bus Error at 0x000000010add5a98
```

ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-darwin22]
And then a very long list of crash report logs.

I thought initially it was something related to a bad installation of ruby.
I tried to reinstall ruby, with rbenv.
It seems that rbenv does not have version 3.1.2 anymore (I checked that via rbenv install -l), but I could still install this version with no bug.
I also tried to remove all ffi library cached and config files manually before reinstalling everything because I thought it was related.

Comment: `rbenv install -l` only lists latest stable versions. But `rbenv install -L` lists all local versions.

Comment: Does the bus error occur only when running rails, or can you also create a small example programm, which runs on bus error?

Comment: I tried to create a very simple rails app and didn't have any problem.